# jquery : save drag and drop position with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

how can we save dragged item with cookies.

I'm using Jquery with this code

```
$("#boxes").sortable({
  handle : '.drag'
});
```

I need to save sortable item with cookies.
Actually I just used tutorial from http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/sortable-lists-using-jquery-ui/

HTML code

```
<ul id="boxes" style="margin-top:5px;">    
    <li id="box1" class="con">
          <div class="drag"></div>
        </li>
    <li id="box2" class="con">
          <div class="drag"></div>
        </li>
    <li id="box3" class="con">
          <div class="drag"></div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Diodeus sorry about that, the code `<li>` have somany so I just copied one line ;) . actually drag and drop working fine. I need to save the item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use local browser storage?

```
localStorage.setItem("boxes", $("#boxes").sortable("toArray"));
```

You could also do this with a cookie, for non-html5 browsers:

```
$.cookie("boxes", $("#boxes").sortable("toArray"), { expires: 7});
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Actually my client is really strict on IE6 :(

Comment: @maanu: Here is a handy plugin for jquery: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/localstorage  If localstorage isn't implemented in the browser, it backends into cookie storage. So you can be forward and backward compatible. Hurrah!